# C++20 "FixedArray" Container (dynamically allocated fixed-size array)

Tags: c++, array, collections, c++20

I've wrote a FixedArray to fit seamlessly (function-wise) with the default C++ containers, including working with algorithms/etc. It is a dynamically allocated, but fixed size array.

### Code

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace Util {
    
    template<typename C, typename T=typename C::value_type>
    concept Container = std::input_iterator<typename C::iterator> && std::is_same_v<typename C::value_type,T> && requires(C c,const C cc,size_t i) {
        { c.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;
        { c.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;
        { cc.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
        { cc.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
        { c.size() } -> std::same_as<typename C::size_type>;
    };
    
    template<typename T, bool _reassignable=false, typename Alloc=std::allocator<T>>
    class FixedArray {
    public:
        
        using value_type=T;
        using allocator_type=Alloc;
        using size_type=size_t;
        using difference_type=std::ptrdiff_t;
        
        using reference=T&;
        using pointer=T*;
        using iterator=T*;
        using reverse_iterator=std::reverse_iterator<T*>;
        
        using const_reference=const T&;
        using const_pointer=const T*;
        using const_iterator=const T*;
        using const_reverse_iterator=std::reverse_iterator<const T*>;
        
    private:
        
        value_type * _data;
        size_type _size;
        
        [[no_unique_address]] Alloc allocator;
        
        void _cleanup() { // destroy all objects, deallocate all memory, leaves container in a valid empty state
            if(_data) {
                for(size_t i=0;i<_size;i++) {
                    _data[i].~value_type();
                }
                allocator.deallocate(_data,_size);
                _data=nullptr;
            }
            _size=0;
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        void _container_assign(const C &container) { // allocate memory and copy contents from generic container of type C
            if(container.size()==0) {
                _size=0;
                _data=nullptr;
            } else {
                _size=container.size();
                _data=allocator.allocate(_size);
                typename C::const_iterator it=container.begin();
                for(size_t i=0;i<_size;i++,it++){
                    new(_data+i) value_type(*it);
                }
            }
        }
        
    public:
        
        FixedArray() : _data(nullptr), _size(0) {
            
        }
        
        FixedArray(std::nullptr_t) : _data(nullptr), _size(0) {
            
        }
        
        FixedArray(std::initializer_list<T> data) requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<value_type> {
            _container_assign(data);
        }
        
        template<typename U>
        FixedArray(std::initializer_list<U> data) requires (!std::is_same_v<T,U>) && requires (U x){ T(x); }
        {
            _container_assign(data);
        }
        
        FixedArray(const FixedArray & other) requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<value_type> {
            _container_assign(other);
        }
        
        FixedArray(FixedArray && other) : _data(other._data), _size(other._size) {
            other._data=nullptr;
            other._size=0;
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        FixedArray(const C& container) requires Container<C,value_type> && std::is_copy_constructible_v<value_type> {
            _container_assign(container);
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        FixedArray(const C& container) requires Container<C> && (!std::is_same_v<T,typename C::value_type>) && requires (typename C::value_type v) { T(v); }
        {
            _container_assign(container);
        }
        
        FixedArray(size_t n) requires std::is_default_constructible_v<value_type> : _data(nullptr), _size(n) {
            if(_size>0){
                _data=allocator.allocate(_size);
                for(size_t i=0;i<_size;i++){
                    new(_data+i) value_type();
                }
            }
        }
        
        ~FixedArray() {
            _cleanup();
        }
        
        // --- optional reassignment methods ---
        
        void operator=(std::nullptr_t) requires _reassignable {
            _cleanup();
        }
        
        void clear() requires _reassignable {
            _cleanup();
        }
        
        FixedArray & operator=(std::initializer_list<T> data) requires _reassignable {
            _cleanup();
            _container_assign(data);
            return *this;
        }
        
        template<typename U>
        FixedArray & operator=(std::initializer_list<U> data) requires _reassignable &&  requires (U x){ T(x); }
        {
            _cleanup();
            _container_assign(data);
            return *this;
        }
        
        FixedArray & operator=(const FixedArray & other) requires _reassignable {
            _cleanup();
            _container_assign(other);
            return *this;
        }
        
        FixedArray & operator=(FixedArray && other) requires _reassignable {
            _cleanup();
            _data=other._data;
            _size=other._size;
            other._data=nullptr;
            other._size=0;
            return *this;
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        FixedArray & operator=(const C& container) requires _reassignable && Container<C,value_type> {
            _cleanup();
            _container_assign(container);
            return *this;
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        FixedArray & operator=(const C& container) requires _reassignable && Container<C> && (!std::is_same_v<T,typename C::value_type>) && requires (typename C::value_type v) { T(v); }
        {
            _cleanup();
            _container_assign(container);
            return *this;
        }
        
        void swap(FixedArray & other) requires _reassignable {
            value_type * temp_data=_data;
            size_t temp_size=_size;
            _data=other._data;
            _size=other._size;
            other._data=temp_data;
            other._size=temp_size;
        }
        
        static void swap(FixedArray & lhs,FixedArray & rhs) requires _reassignable {
            lhs.swap(rhs);
        }
        
        // --- container boilerplate after this ---
        
        template<typename C>
        bool operator==(const C& container) const {
            return _size==container.size()&&std::equal(container.begin(),container.end(),begin(),end());
        }
        
        template<typename C>
        bool operator!=(const C& container) const {
            return _size!=container.size()||!std::equal(container.begin(),container.end(),begin(),end());
        }
        
        size_type size() const noexcept {
            return _size;
        }
        
        static size_type max_size() noexcept {
            return (std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()/sizeof(value_type))-1;
        }
        
        size_type empty() const noexcept {
            return _size==0;
        }
        
        iterator begin() noexcept {
            return _data;
        }
        
        iterator end() noexcept {
            return _data+_size;
        }
        
        const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
            return _data;
        }
        
        const_iterator end() const noexcept {
            return _data+_size;
        }
        
        const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
            return _data;
        }
        
        const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
            return _data+_size;
        }
        
        reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }
        
        reverse_iterator rend() noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }
        
        const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }
        
        const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }
        
        const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(end());
        }
        
        const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept {
            return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin());
        }
        
        pointer data() noexcept {
            return _data;
        }
        
        const_pointer data() const noexcept {
            return _data;
        }
        
        reference front() noexcept {
            return _data[0];
        }
        
        const_reference front() const noexcept {
            return _data[0];
        }
        
        reference back() noexcept {
            return _data[_size-1];
        }
        
        const_reference back() const noexcept {
            return _data[_size-1];
        }
        
        reference operator[](size_t i) noexcept {
            return _data[i];
        }
        
        const_reference operator[](size_t i) const noexcept {
            return _data[i];
        }
        
        reference at(size_t i) {
            if(i>=_size) throw std::out_of_range("Index "+std::to_string(i)+" is out of range for FixedArray of size "+std::to_string(_size));
            return _data[i];
        }
        
        const_reference at(size_t i) const {
            if(i>=_size) throw std::out_of_range("Index "+std::to_string(i)+" is out of range for FixedArray of size "+std::to_string(_size));
            return _data[i];
        }
        
    };
}
```

After testing it, it *seems* to work without any problems, but a second pair of eyes could help find anything i might have overlooked.

Comment: Can you outline any important differences between this and [`std::Array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @Edward you can construct this from any Container-like object (vector/etc), and since it is dynamically allocated, the size doesn't need to be known at compile-time

Comment: It looks like a lot of work for what is basically a `std::vector` that you just never resize. Why would someone want to use this class over `std::vector`? The latter also allows construction from any other container-like object, given two iterators.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Why is there a need to critize OP doing this project? This website is meant for people to receive constructive criticism on working code, which this is.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I've written it more of as a `std::array` than a `std::vector`, it is useful in places where you know that the size won't change (or where it _must_ not change), but at the same time the size isn't known at compile time, it also has slightly less memory overhead due to needing to store less data, but that's negligible (8 bytes on GCC)

Comment: @TomGebel I'm asking this because it is important to understand what the code is intended for. Is it for the OP to excercise building a C++ container? Or is it meant for actual production code?

Comment: @G.Sliepen While not meant for 'production' per-se, it is intended to be used, although in a hobby project

Comment: Nice: The one thing I would note is that arrays/std::vector/std::array etc destroy the objects in reverse order of creation. I would change your clean up to call destructors from `(n --> 0]` to mimik this behavior.

Comment: Some more optimizations that I implemented for vector that may help here: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/19/vector-simple-optimizations/index.html

Comment: Surprised no one has mentioned the overloads of `std::unique_ptr` yet. They’re even more similar. Anyway, unless you’re reinventing the wheel on purpose as an exercise, don’t/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Consider not using this class

Your class basically reimplements almost all of `std::vector`, except the functions that resized the container. The only feature I can see that it has over regular `std::vector` is that you can easily assign another container to it without using a pair of iterators. In this case, I would recommend considering not using this class, but just a regular `std::vector`, so that you don't have to maintain this code.

Alternatively, you could perhaps consider deriving your class from `std::vector`, but delete all the functions that resize. For example:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class FixedArray: public std::vector<T, Alloc> {
public:
    // Delete functions you don't want:
    void resize(size_t) = delete;
    ...

    // Pull in the constructors of the parent class:
    using std::vector<T, Alloc>::vector;

    // Add more constructors/functions if needed:
    template<typename C>
    FixedArray(const C& container) : std::vector<T, Alloc>(std::begin(container), std::end(container)) {}
    ...
};
```

Inheriting from a container class this way has its own drawbacks, so I wouldn't recommend this either, but I do think this approach will require much less code to be written.

For the rest of the review I'm assuming you do want to use your own class as it is.

## Make better use of existing concepts

Instead of defining your own `concept Container`, make use of the concepts from the Ranges library, like [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range), or even better the more specific ones like [`std::ranges::input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range).

Also, instead of writing `requires (typename C::value_type v) { T(v); }`, consider using [`requires std::is_constructible_v<T, C::value_type>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible).

## Use concepts directly inside a `template` parameter list

A nice thing about concepts is that you can use them instead of `typename` in a `template` parameter list. This avoids some typing, and makes the code a little easier to read. For example, instead of:

```
template<typename C>
FixedArray(const C& container) requires Container<C> && (!std::is_same_v<T,typename C::value_type>) && requires (typename C::value_type v) { T(v); }
{
    _container_assign(container);
}
```

You can write:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range C>
FixedArray(const C& container) requires (!std::is_same_v<T,typename C::value_type> && std::is_constructible_v(T, C::value_type))
{
    _container_assign(container);
}
```

## Use default member value initialization

You can avoid some typing by using member value initialization:

```
pointer _data{};
size_type _size{};
```

This avoids repeating the default initialization in several of the constructors. In fact, this way the default constructor can really be made `default`:

```
FixedArray() = default;
```

## Avoid code duplication

There are several ways you can reduce the amount of code you have written:

### Reuse your own functions

You can make use of your own member functions and iterators. For example, you can use range-`for` to loop over the elements of `_data`:

```
void _cleanup() { // destroy all objects, deallocate all memory, leaves container in a valid empty state
    if(_data) {
        for(auto &el: *this) {
            el.~value_type();
        }
        allocator.deallocate(_data, _size);
        _data = nullptr;
    }
    _size = 0;
}
```

Also, when moving data from another container, make use of your own `swap()` function. Combined with the default member initialization, this removes a lot of lines, for example the move constructor becomes:

```
FixedArray(FixedArray && other) {
    swap(other);
}
```

### Merge (template) overloads where possible

There are several places where you have multiple overloads for dealing with other containers of the same `value_type` or of another, when they can be merged into one. For example, the constructors taking initializer lists can be merged into this single one:

```
template<typename U>
FixedArray(std::initializer_list<U> data) requires std::is_constructible_v<value_type, U>
{
    _container_assign(data);
}
```

Since this will also handle the case of a `std::initializer_list<value_type>` just fine. The same goes for the other cases where you used `!std::is_same_v<>`.

### Define `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`

It's always best to define one of those operators in terms of the other, so you cannot have a small mistake give subtly different behaviour. So:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range C>
bool operator!=(const C& container) const {
    return !operator==(container);
}
```

## Be consistent using `std::size()`, `std::begin()` and `std::end()`

To ensure your class works with all possible containers, don't use member functions `.size()`, `.begin()` and `.end()` directly, but use the free-standing `std::size()` and related functions. For example:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range C>
bool operator==(const C& container) const {
    return std::equal(std::begin(container), std::end(container), begin(), end());
}
```

Note that you also don't need to use `std::size()` in this example, `std::equal()` will already check whether the sizes match.

## Use your own type aliases consistently

If you define an alias, you should use it yourself as well. This ensures that if you need to change a type, you only need to do it on one line. So replace `size_t` with `size_type` everywhere, use `value_type` instead of `T` in a few places, and so on.

## Use consistent code formatting

Your code does not use consistent formatting, in some places there are spaces around operators, in other places there are none. I recommend using a code formatting tool to do this for you, for example [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) or [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: I'd argue that it's better to use a `std::vector` as a member, or to inherit from it *privately*, than to use public inheritance like that (where one could find it used as the base class, and therefore resized unexpectedly).

Comment: @TobySpeight Indeed, that's one of the issues that inheritance has. But either private inheritance or making it a member value would mean writing a lot of wrapper functions.

Comment: I think private inheritance would just need lots of `using` base-class functions rather than wrappers.  Still lots of them, of course (but only one for each identifier, not for each override).

Answer (score 3):

G. Sliepen's answer covers some good ideas already, but here are some additional points.

**Memory leak: Exception safety**

If a T has a constructor that throws, and a constructor does throw in the loop of `_container_assign`, you've got a leak.  You'll have allocated memory already, and the pointer member might have been "constructed", but since it's a raw pointer, its "destructor" won't release the memory.  Similarly, [because your class's constructor hasn't finished, the object itself wasn't fully constructed, so its own destructor won't be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212842/what-destructors-are-run-when-the-constructor-throws-an-exception), meaning any T objects whose construction finished won't have their destructors called (and if they in turn also own resources, those will also leak).

You could change your requirements to require noexcept constructors, or you could include try/catch logic to handle cleanup before rethrowing.

There's a similar, but different, concern if an exception is thrown in the loop of `_cleanup`, but throwing an exception in a destructor is such a bad practice that you might just refuse to support it.  You might consider a static_assert or requires clause that the destructor of T is noexcept to enforce that refusal at compile-time.

**Concept: finish meeting Allocator_Aware by supporting stateful allocators**

If the allocator is always default-constructed, there is no way to get state in there, which means stateful allocators cannot be used.  Some kinds of custom allocators make more sense to implement with state, even if it is just a pointer to some other object.

This can be remedied by adding constructor overloads that accept an allocator as a parameter (see: [allocator-aware containers on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer)).  Make use of `std::allocator_traits` to check if the allocator needs to be propagated on copies, swaps, moves.

You probably want to be using `std::allocator_traits` anyway so your size_type, pointer, and difference_type aliases to be consistent with your allocator.

**Generality: Support types that are movable but not copyable**

Your requires clauses in the constructor overloads and copy function are all about copy construction, which is fine if you don't want to modify the contents of a container, but if you add overloads for non-const references for objects that are move-constructible, you could have things like arrays of `std::unique_ptr`.

You might use something like [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) in the implementation of those overloads, so that your assignment implementation could be templated on iterator type, taking move_iterators from the non-const overloads and const_iterators from the const overloads.

**Potential improvement: more noexcept**

Move constructor in particular most likely can be noexcept, and [this can improve performance if someone wants a std::vector of your array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66498981/6600922).  To be safe, you can use the noexcept operator to make it noexcept if and only if size_type and pointer can be noexcept copied.

Swap and move assignment could do the same; though the linked answer suggests the standard library probably won't notice or care, libraries evolve over time, and there may be other code you end up using that does notice and care.

You might also consider making the destructor (and thus `_cleanup`) noexcept as well, maybe conditionally so if `~T()` and `allocator.deallocate(pointer)` are noexcept.  Especially so if you followed the earlier suggestion of enforcing that `~T()` has to be noexcept, and want to be able to have an array of arrays.

**Potential improvement: more constexpr**

The default (and nullptr) constructors could have been constexpr even before c++20, but now that for example `std::allocator` can be constexpr, you could very well have a non-empty constexpr object of your class, which means more member functions might also make sense as constexpr, which would also be consistent with the updates to the standard library containers.

Note that unlike noexcept, [you can usually just put constexpr on templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41517864/6600922) as long as it could be constexpr for some type.

**Consider construction from raw pointer, size, and allocator**

This would allow you to emulate move ("stealing") construction for arrays that were already created without RAII, so long as you know what their allocator is.  For example, arrays obtained from a C function that is known to allocate them via malloc could be "moved" into an object provided with an allocator that wraps malloc/free ( [`std::allocator` calls `::operator new` which might not call malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313727/difference-between-malloc-and-stdallocatortallocate), so wrapping malloc/free is the way to guarantee their usage).

If you never deal with C libraries nor older c++ code, this probably wouldn't come up, since newer c++ code mostly uses RAII, but it is not so difficult to add this support if you are already supporting custom allocators, and this is something `std::vector` *does not* do.

**Very minor nitpick about the move assignment:**

In addition to G. Sliepen's point about reducing duplication, having the move assignment call `swap` [has the benefit of better tolerance of self-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322174/move-assignment-operator-and-if-this-rhs/9322542#9322542).  Doing so defers the cleanup until the object referred to by the passed rvalue reference is destroyed, instead of cleaning up first, but you already had to clean up an expiring object, so there's no extra cost in the normal case, you just pay the same cost some number of instructions later.  What you gain is that self move-assignment aka `*this = std::move(*this)` no longer destroys contents.  While it would be silly to purposefully self move-assign, it might come up accidentally in some generic template code.